# Any thoughts on what this IC might be (from a McDonald's toy)?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I'm looking for a datasheet or some indication on the function of this 4-pin IC, which I removed from a McDonald's toy.  The IC is marked with 2MEE KRDB.

[image]

The disconnected pins (1 and 4) are V+ and GND respectively and was running on 3V.

The IC is attached to a speaker and a smaller coil (see below).  When the toy is bumped, a coil vibrates near the speaker magnet, producing a current to switch-on the IC.  Some music then plays through the speaker (though I can't get this to work reliably anymore after removing it from the toy).  Each end of the coil are attached respectively to pins 2 and 3 of the IC.

[image][image]

I was hoping to see if the IC is programmable -- would be a nice gadget to have!

Comment: Cheap 8bit micro with masked ROM.

Comment: In other words: not reprogrammable.

Comment: Mc ideee buys in high volume could be anything

Comment: There are low-cost processors available from Taiwan and maybe the PRC that literally have the entire memory contents etched into metal layers of the IC. Lead time is a few weeks. Minimum order quantity is around a thousand or few thousand parts. These go into plush toys and audible greeting cards and other high volume, low cost items.